# serialize list Trying to serialize data within list

Tags: javascript

I have a form. After filling the form out you can add or delete an entry from the list. This all works fine. What I am tying to get working is once all the entries are added to the list and the person hits submit, Iwant to serialize the data within the list.

form submission is what I been working on so far and I got it to where it comes back with the most recent entry but not all within the list.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home builder</title>
    <style>
        .debug {
            font-family: monospace;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Household builder</h1>
    <div class="builder">
        <ol class="household"></ol>
        <form name="myForm" method="post" >
            <div>
                <label>Age
                    <input type="text" name="age">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Relationship
                    <select name="rel">
                        <option value="">---</option>
                        <option value="self">Self</option>
                        <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                        <option value="child">Child</option>
                        <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                        <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Smoker?
                    <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="house">Home
                    <select id="homelist" size="9">
                    <option></option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button"      onclick="validateForm()">add</button>

                <button type="button" onclick="removeList()">Remove</button>

                <button type="submit" onclick="Submission()">submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- <div id="results"> </div> -->
    </div>
    <pre class="debug" id="results"> </pre>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >

        function Submission() {
            var x = $('#household :input').serializeArray();
            $.each(x, function(i, field){
                $("#results").append(field.name + ":" + field.value + " ");
            })
        }
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
            if  (isNaN(x)|| x == ""|| x < 0) {
                alert("Age must be filled out and must be greater than 0");
                return false;
            }
            else
                addList();
        }
        function addList() {
            var x = document.getElementById("homelist");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = ("Relationship: "+ document.forms["myForm"]["rel"].value + " Age: "+document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value+" Smoker: "+document.forms["myForm"]["smoker"].checked);
            x.add(option)
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using `.serialize()` jQuery method ? Check the example on this page: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/